# Cannot index document

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I have written some code using the Elasticsearch.Net & NEST client library that should index a document without using a POCO for mapping fields as I have many different documents.

Question 1) Is this correct way to do create an index, does the `.AddMapping<string>(mapping => mapping.Dynamic(true))` create the mapping based on the document passed in?

```cs
var newIndex = client.CreateIndex(indexName, index => index
    .NumberOfReplicas(replicas)
    .NumberOfShards(shards)
    .Settings(settings => settings
    .Add("merge.policy.merge_factor", "10")
    .Add("search.slowlog.threshold.fetch.warn", "1s")
   )
    .AddMapping<string>(mapping => mapping.Dynamic(true))
);
```

Question 2) Is this possible?

```cs
string document = "{\"name\": \"Mike\"}";
var newIndex = client.Index(document, indexSelector => indexSelector
        .Index(indexName)
 );
```

When I run code in "Question 2" it returns:
`{"Unable to perform request: 'POST ' on any of the nodes after retrying 0 times."}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NEST only deals with typed objects in this case passing a string will cause it to index the document into `/{indexName}/string/{id}`.

Since it can't infer an id from string and you do not pass it one it will fail on that or on the fact that it can't serialize a string. I'll update the client to throw a better exception in this case.

If you want to index a document as string use the exposed `Elasticsearch.NET` client like so:

```
client.Raw.Index(indexName, typeName, id, stringJson);
```

If you want elasticsearch to come up with an id you can use

```
client.Raw.Index(indexName, type, stringJson);
```

`client` is the `NEST`client and the `Raw` property is an `Elasticsearch.Net` client with the same connectionsettings.

Please note that I might rename `Raw` with `LowLevel` in the next beta update, still debating that.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on the typeName.

Comment: an elasticsearch document is qualified by two pieces an index and typename. the index name specifies where the document lives and the typename specifies what the document type is and what mappings should be applied.

Comment: thanks, so what will happen if I don't specify a mapping when I create an index and include a typeName when indexing `stringJson`?

Comment: A mapping is a combination of the index/type (so the same type can have a different mapping under a different index). Mappings are dynamic by default so when you present a document with new properties it will update the mapping automatically.)

Comment: Ok I see, I was also wondering if one would have to set the index mapping to dynamic when creating the index. Thanks for the help.